# how to get the type of a doctrine entity property

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Actually I have a doctrine entity that I need to fill its prperties dynamically.

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
$entity = new Entity();
$reflect = new ReflectionClass($entity);
// $fields is an array whihch contain the entity name as the array key and the value as the array value
foreach ($fields as $key => $val)
{
    if (!reflect->hasProperty($key)) {
        var_dump('the entity does not have a such property');
        continue;
    }
    if ( the type of $key is string ) {
          // convert $value to utf8
    } elseif ( the type of $key is integer) {
          // do something else
    } //....etc
}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: You could simply use [doctrines metadata](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.4/class-Doctrine.ORM.Mapping.ClassMetadata.html). It will propably provide all the infos you need about your entities.

Comment: Exactly the same as getProperty($key)->getDocComment, won't provide better information. I guess the only way is to get the property comment/annotations and parse it

Comment: Gotcha :), took me a while though. thx

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found [the solution thanks to @Yoshi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27293233/how-to-get-the-type-of-a-doctrine-entity-property/27294975#comment43052209_27293233). I hope it'll help

```
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;

$docReader = new AnnotationReader();
$entity = new Entity();
$reflect = new ReflectionClass($entity);
// $fields is an array whihch contain the entity name as the array key and the value as the array value
foreach ($fields as $key => $val)
{
    if (!reflect->hasProperty($key)) {
        var_dump('the entity does not have a such property');
        continue;
    }
    $docInfos = $docReader->getPropertyAnnotations($reflect->getProperty($key));
    if ( $docInfos[0]->type === 'string' ) {
          // convert $value to utf8
    } elseif ( $docInfos[0]->type === 'integer' ) {
          // do something else
    } //....etc
}
```

Comment: Don't you mean that key is the FIELD name and not the entity name?

Answer (score 4):

Old as it is, this post was really useful when we needed a workaround for boolean fields being always set to true in some contexts -- thank you smarber and yoshi. Our workaround detects boolean fields (in PATCH, in this case) and uses the corresponding setter to propagate the value. (Of course, it would be nice if this weren't necessary.)

```
/*
 * @PATCH("/entity/{name}")
 */
public function patchEntityAction(Request $request, $entity)
{
    ...

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    // handle booleans
    $metadata      = $manager->getClassMetadata($bundle_entity);
    $entity_fields = $metadata->getFieldNames();
    foreach ($entity_fields as $field) {
        $type = $metadata->getTypeOfField($field);
        if ($request->request->has("$field") && $type == 'boolean') {
            $setter = 'set' . ucfirst($field);
            $entity->$setter(!!$request->request->get("$field"));
        }
    }

    $manager->persist($entity);
    $manager->flush();

    ...

}
```

Ref: https://api.symfony.com/3.4/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html

Comment: So useful! Both answers work but I like this one because of it's simplicity

Answer (score 1):

You can use [gettype](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php)

```
$entity = new Entity();
$reflect = new ReflectionClass($entity);
// $fields is an array whihch contain the entity name as the array key and the value as the array value
foreach ($fields as $key => $val)
{
    if (!reflect->hasProperty($key)) {
        var_dump('the entity does not have a such property');
        continue;
    }
    if ( gettype($key) === "integer" ) {
          // convert $value to utf8
    } elseif ( gettype($key) === "string") {
          // do something else
    } //....etc
}
```

Comment: This won't work because my entity properties are not set initially

Answer (score 1):

For case if you have few different annotations for entity field in any order.
*Note: this code is not detect related entities (ManyToOne, OneToMany and etc).*

```
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;

/**
 * @param $entity
 * @param $fieldName
 * @return mixed|null
 */
private function getFieldType($entity, $fieldName)
{
    $annotationReader = new AnnotationReader();
    $refClass = new ReflectionClass($entity);
    $annotations = $annotationReader->getPropertyAnnotations($refClass->getProperty($fieldName));

    if (count($annotations) > 0) {
        foreach ($annotations as $annotation) {
            if (
                $annotation instanceof \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column
                && property_exists($annotation, 'type')
            ) {
                return $annotation->type;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```