# get the type of the parameter in a set property

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

Using Symfony 2 framework, I have entities from database with annotation.

In my particular case, I work with entities but I dont know which one I am using.

Let's say I have an entity object $entity

```
$class = get_class($entity);
$reflect = new \ReflectionClass($class)
$properties = $reflect->getProperties();

foreach($properties as $property) {
   $entity->{'set' .ucfirst(strtolower($property))}($some_value);
   ....
}
```

Is there a way to know for each property, what type of parameter it expects ? using the annotation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get the type of a doctrine entity property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27293233/how-to-get-the-type-of-a-doctrine-entity-property)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory you could do this, but I don't know how it will impact the performance.
You can use the Doctrine AnnotationReader for this.

Here is a code example of what you could do.

```
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;

$class = get_class($entity);
$reflect = new \ReflectionClass($class)
$properties = $reflect->getProperties();
$annotationReader = new AnnotationReader();

foreach($properties as $property) {
    $reflectionProperty = new ReflectionProperty($class, $property);
    $propertyAnnotations = $annotationReader->getPropertyAnnotations($reflectionProperty);
    var_dump($propertAnnotations);
    ....
}
```

Besides this, you might want to look into the Symfony ProppertyAccesor for getting and/or setting specific object values.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access/introduction.html