# How to set the DateTime timezone programatically on user login in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, timezone

I need to improve the application of my work that I’ve done in Symfony2 now that we’re expanding to an international level and we must implement a system of time zones so that that each user can modify the date that they will receive notifications and other alerts.  Our time zone of origin is UTC+1 (Europe/Madrid) so we have to save the dates in the database with this time zone. But when it comes to the app, it should be able to show in the settings the time that user configured.

How can I implement it in Symfony 2 so that I won’t have to modify all of the controllers and twig templates?

Can it be done in event listener?

Comment: what about calling `date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok");` as part of your e.g. `app.php` and `app_dev.php` but you can call it whereever it fits in your application.

Comment: Thanks for answering :). So calling that function will affect the insertion of dateTime in DDBB ?

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found a solution, getting your information and searching similar things, specially this --> [how to get the type of a doctrine entity property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27293233/how-to-get-the-type-of-a-doctrine-entity-property/27294975#27294975) helped me to develop the final code.

Here is what I done:

1. I've extended the DateTime of Doctrine into a new class UTCDateTimeType:

   ```
   use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;
   use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\ConversionException;
   use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateTimeType;

   class UTCDateTimeType extends DateTimeType {

       static private $utc;

       static function getUtc(){

           return self::$utc;
       }

       public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
       {
           if ($value instanceof \DateTime) {
               $value->setTimezone(self::getUtc());
           }

           return parent::convertToDatabaseValue($value, $platform);
       }

       public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
       {   

           if (null === $value || $value instanceof \DateTime) {
               return $value;
           }

           $converted = \DateTime::createFromFormat(
               $platform->getDateTimeFormatString(),
               $value,
               self::$utc ? self::$utc : self::$utc = new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Madrid')
           );

           if (! $converted) {
               throw ConversionException::conversionFailedFormat(
                   $value,
                   $this->getName(),
                   $platform->getDateTimeFormatString()
               );
           }

           return $converted;
       }
   }
   ```

   So when get or persit the data of datetime, it's allways in my UTC timezone.
2. Then, before bootstrapping the ORM, I've overrided the datetime types:

   ```
   Type::overrideType('datetime', UTCDateTimeType::class);
   Type::overrideType('datetimetz', UTCDateTimeType::class);
   ```
3. I edited my User entity to have a time zone field ( PHP time zone identifier)
4. On a LoginListener -> onSecurityInteractiveLogin, I've injected the Session and when a user log in, I set a "timezone" variable to Session with the user time zone field.

   ```
   public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event){
       $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
       $this->session->set("timezone",new \DateTimeZone($user->getTimeZone()));
       // ...
   }
   ```
5. I made a TimeZoneListener which listen to **postLoad** doctrine event (triggered when an Entity is fully loaded from DDBB)

   ```
   use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
   use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
   use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface;
   use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
   use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;

   class TimeZoneListener {

       protected $session;

       protected $container;

       protected $router;

       protected $securityContext;

       protected $translator;

       protected $docReader;

       public function __construct(RouterInterface $router, Session $session, TranslatorInterface $translator, $container){

           $this->session = $session;
           $this->router = $router;
           $this->translator = $translator;
           $this->container = $container;
           $this->docReader = new AnnotationReader();
       }

       public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args){

           $reader = $this->docReader;
           $entity = $args->getEntity();
           $reflect = new \ReflectionClass($entity);

           $props = $reflect->getProperties();

           foreach($props as $prop){

               $docInfos = $reader->getPropertyAnnotations($prop);
               foreach($docInfos as $info){

                   if(!$info instanceof \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column) continue;
                   if($info->type !== "datetime") continue;

                   $getDateMethod = 'get'.ucfirst($prop->getName());

                   $val = $entity->{$getDateMethod}();
                   if($val){
                       $val->setTimeZone($this->session->get("timezone") ? $this->session->get("timezone") : new \DateTimeZone("Europe/Madrid"));

                   }

               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
6. In **postLoad** method I search for each property of type **datetime** and then I set to logged user timeZone (previously setted at login into session)
7. Now, each time a entity is loaded, when a datetime field is reached, at  render stage, the datetime offset is sucessfully applied and for each user it displays as spected.

Comment: IMO, referencing [the official Doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/working-with-datetime.html) would make sense ;-)

Answer (score -1):

1) Set default timezone, i.e. in event listener that listens `kernel.request` event.

2) Create event listener that listens `security.interactive_login` event and there extract user from the event, then get his own timezone settings and apply. ([An example](https://matt.drollette.com/2012/07/user-specific-timezones-with-symfony2-and-twig-extensions/))

Comment: your link is dead!