# Getting property type when using typed properties in Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, php-8

Prior to Doctrine ORM 2.9, we could detect the property type by using the ReflectionClass and a code like:

```php
$type = \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::getType($attribute->getArguments()['type']);
```

Now that we can define properties like following, How do I detect the property type using Reflection class? I tried to detect it by AttributeReader, but it returns an empty type.

```php
#[ORM\Column(length: 64)]
private string $name;
```

Indeed, solutions like https://stackoverflow.com/a/27294975/16430519 doesn't seem to work when using typed properties.

Comment: You should be able to do this with the PHP reflections.

Comment: @MarkusZeller can you post an example?